# I'm trying to hawe two QFrames take exactly half of the QMainWindow. An offset is being forced and I can't seem to get rid of it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm just experimenting with PyQt5 so I can figure out some problems in another program I'm writing, but the biggest thing is that I can't seem to figure out how exactly to change a widget's geometry.

I wrote this small test window with two frames of different colors and I'm trying to have them split the entire possible space.

```
class Test(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(300, 300), QSize(300, 300)))

        self._centralWidget = QWidget()
        self._centralLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
        self._centralWidget.setLayout(self._centralLayout)

        self.initGUI()
        self.show()

    def initGUI(self):
        self.leftFrame = QFrame()
        self.leftFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color:red")
        self.leftFrame.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0, 0), QSize(150, 300)))  # Same as QRect(0, 0, 150, 300)

        self.rightFrame = QFrame()
        self.rightFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color:green")
        self.rightFrame.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(150, 0), QSize(150, 300)))  # Same as QRect(150, 0, 150, 300)

        self._centralLayout.addWidget(self.leftFrame)
        self._centralLayout.addWidget(self.rightFrame)
```

---

The MainWindow is 300x300, so I set the two frames to be 150x300. When I run it though, there's an annoying offset of 9x9. So the true sizes of the two frames are: left frame: `QRect(9, 9, 138, 282)` | right frame: `QRect(153, 9, 138, 282)`.

[image: Test MainWindow]

I have a suspicion that it might be the QHBoxLayout that is messing with sizes but I'm not sure. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manually set the geometry then you **should not use layouts** since the very objective of layouts is to automate their handling based on their characteristics.

```
def initGUI(self):
    self.leftFrame = QFrame(self._centralWidget)
    self.leftFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color:red")
    self.leftFrame.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0, 0), QSize(150, 300)))

    self.rightFrame = QFrame(self._centralWidget)
    self.rightFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color:green")
    self.rightFrame.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(150, 0), QSize(150, 300)))
```

If you want to use layouts then it is not necessary to use setGeometry in the QFrames, you must also set the margins and spaces of the layout to 0:

```
def initGUI(self):
    self.leftFrame = QFrame()
    self.leftFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color:red")
    
    self.rightFrame = QFrame()
    self.rightFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color:green")

    self._centralLayout.addWidget(self.leftFrame)
    self._centralLayout.addWidget(self.rightFrame)
    self._centralLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self._centralLayout.setSpacing(0)
```